# Reciprocal of midsegment (midpoint) theorem proof

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I need a hint on how to prove that "In a triangle ABC if D is the midpoint of the side AB and the line through D intersects AC at E such that BC=2DE then E is the midpoint of AC and BC is parallel to DE"

Thank you

Comment: Assume that $E$ is not the mid-point and prove by contradiction.

Comment: VVR, sure, I tried , but haven't succeeded. By the way the proof you posted and then deleted, has a mistake I think. In △ADE: ∢A+∢ADF+∢FDE=∢A+∢ADE=180°-∢AED not 180°-∢AFD as you wrote... And the proof hasn't used the info that DE=BC/2 so of course it is wrong, how could it be true..

Comment: I know that, that's the reason I deleted it

Comment: There is a problem: if AC > AB > BC then there's another solution with E not the midpoint of AC. Consider drawing an arc centred on D with radius ½BC; it will intersect AC at its midpoint and another point.

Comment: "There is a problem: if AC > AB > BC then there's another solution with E not the midpoint of AC. Consider drawing an arc centred on D with radius ½BC; it will intersect AC at its midpoint and another point." Can't visualize it, can you please show a drawing ?

Comment: This has grown to a lot more than "a hint", so I'm not going to rush to draw something. Rather than "visualizing", try using a ruler, a compass, a pencil, and a sheet of paper. Hopefully you'll see it without me needing to draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\triangle ABC$ , if we apply the law of sine, we get:

$$ \frac{BC}{\sin\angle BAC} = \frac{AB}{\sin\angle ACB}$$

or, $$\frac{BC}{AB} = \frac{\sin\angle BAC}{\sin\angle ACB}    $$

Now, In $\triangle ADE$

$$ \frac{DE}{\sin\angle BAC} = \frac{AD}{\sin\angle AED}$$

or, $$ \frac{\frac{BC}{2}}{\sin\angle BAC} = \frac{\frac{AB}{2}}{\sin\angle AED}$$

or, $$\frac{BC}{AB} = \frac{\sin\angle BAC}{\sin\angle AED} $$

Therefore, $$\sin\angle ACB = \sin\angle AED$$

Comment: Nice, thank you

Comment: As I've alluded to elsewhere, sinφ = sinθ does not prove φ = θ, and indeed, the proof you seek does not exist for precisely this reason. But since my answer has been downvoted, I assume you're not interested in my helping you further. (Hint: you're only supposed to downvote answers that are wrong or misleading, not just because they're not "the best".)

Comment: @Martin Kealey, I agree with you, the question is not exactly the converse of mid-point theorem. My answer just proves that there are two possibilities, either $E$ is the mid-point of $AC$ or $\angle ACB + \angle AED = 180^\circ$, which is a completely different situation.

Comment: Martin, I haven't downvoted by the way. It must be other readers who did, and of course I am interested in you helping me further. If we add the condition that BC>AB, will this be enough to ensure that E will be the middle of AC ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

a proof of the question as stated *does not exist*, as it's easy to construct a counterexample:

A circle of radius ½BC centred on D intersects (the infinite continuation of) AC at E and E’; for some triangles E’ will be between A and C, and therefore a line DE’ has length ½BC while *not* being parallel to BC.

E’ is a solution to "intersects at E" in the problem statement, which implies a "for all E" quantifier. If you're missing a "there exists" quantifier for E, then that quantifier would also allow satisfaction of "two-sides-and-any-angle makes a similar triangle", rebutting your objection in the comments below.

Original:
Looks like a simple case of similar triangles, therefore the angles are the same, therefore...

Start by constructing DE as parallel, then show that it's half of BC. Then work backwards to form a complete proof.

Remember to confirm that parallellism is both necessary and sufficient (ie the interference is reversible).

Comment: why are they similar ? we only know two pairs of proportional sides, we don't know that the pair of angles between these sides are congruent.

Comment: You know a shared angle as well

Comment: "You know a shared angle as well"
No, we don't. 
"Start by constructing DE as parallel, then show that it's half of BC." We are not allowed to assume that it is parallel. We only assume it is half of BC, and we have to prove that it is parallel

Comment: The point is to run the proof in reverse, and then confirm that each step is reversible

Comment: The shared angle is ∡BAC = ∡DAF

Comment: That angle is not the angle formed by the sides which are proportional. ASS or SSA is not a similarity case

Comment: The relevant proportionality is AD/AB = AE/AC.
prove that BC∥DE if-and-only-if ABC and ADE are similar.

Comment: "prove that BC∥DE if-and-only-if ABC and ADE are similar."
But we don't know they are similar. We don't know AD/AB=AE/AC . We only know AD/AB=DE/BC
You claim that the other proof gets to this and it is reversible, please show the steps

Comment: If they can be dissimilar then you have DISproved the original hypothesis (see comment on the question above).

Comment: Maybe they cannot be dissimilar, the question is how to prove they cannot be dissimilar.

Comment: You can't, because a circle may intersect a line at TWO points. There are two solutions to "a line of length X from point P meeting line YZ"

Comment: If you want an interactive explanation, return to libera##math

Comment: "That angle is not the angle formed by the sides which are proportional. ASS or SSA is not a similarity case". There are at most two possible triangles given two sides and an angle; if there are two then one of them is similar and the other is not. These correspond to ADE and ADE’ in my revised explanation above.

Answer (score -1):

Name the midpoint of BC as F and join this point with the midpoint of AB (i.e. D). With this, use the midpoint theorem to conclude that DF is parallel to AC. With a little angle chasing and using one of the congruence theorems, we can prove that $\Delta ADE$ is congruent to $\Delta DBF$. From here, it will be obvious that DE is parallel to BC.

Comment: I got that AD=DB, ∢DAE=∢BDF and DE=BF but it is not enough
to use of the congruence postulates. How to chase one extra pair of congruent angles?